# How can I get existing URL and use as link in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I get existing URL and use as link in jQuery, example?

If my browser is on page  `mysite.com/index.php?page=post&see=11`
I want use URL in my link and add    `/new/` after domain name like this :

```
<a href="mysite.com/new/index.php?page=post&see=11">link text</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - We're here to help, not to write code for you. Show us what you've tried so far and we'll help you find your mistakes. But literally nobody will write code for you. Without you showing us any effort to solve your problem, we won't do so neither.

Comment: i need it for jquery

Comment: This will help you [window.location...](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) you could get the URL as a string and work with it...

Comment: DIEGO CARRASCAL  it get full url and how can i change it

Comment: What do you mean by "how can i change it"? Your question tells nothing about changing the URL to anything else

Comment: Adding "new/" to the string. Ones I didn't know also how to work with strings... I recommend you (@arkonasi) to read about these things, the web that I linked you is very simple and you could learn these basic things from it.  good look.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you [window.location...](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) you could get the URL as a string and work with it. Find ".com/" within the string, split it and then concatenate the two half with "new/" in the middle. After that, you can use it to create the link or navigate to it... or do

```
<a id="newLink" href="#" id="demo">my link</a> 
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var newURL = window.location.hostname.toString();
   newURL = newURL + "new/";
   newURL = newURL + window.location.pathname.toString(); 
   $("#newLink").attr("href", newURL);  
  });
</script>
```

Comment: this is corect? <a href="#" id="demo">my link</a>
<script>
var newURL = window.location.hostname + "new/" + window.location.pathname; 
</script>

Comment: Almost correct, you need to update the `href` with the value of `newURL`.  If you are using jQuery: `$('#demo').attr('href', newURL);`

Comment: how can i use it only for <a href="#" >my link</a>

Comment: plz provide full example i didn't understand

Comment: You can't.  The only way to update an `href` is with Javascript.  Javascript must have some way finding the intended `<a>` tag; having an `id` attribute is one (good) way.

Comment: this is not working it change url for all <a href="#"  >

Comment: and i did not add  new/

Comment: it is not working plz check

Comment: The `id` should be unique for each element, please share the code you are using HTML and Script. I assure you this works, so I must be missing something that your code introduces.

Comment: This last update may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

```
window.location.pathname //returns the path (only);
window.location.href //returns the full URL; and
window.location.hostname //returns the domain name of the web host.
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
var url = window.location.hostname + 'new/' + window.location.pathname;
```

---

If you want to insert `new` in another part in the URL, you can use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
var newUrl = window.location.href.split('/'); //create one array element at every /
newUrl.splice(3, 0, 'new'); //insert 'new' in the position 3
newUrl = newUrl.join('/'); //join every array element with '/' in a string

console.log(newUrl);
```

Updating the `<a>` href

```js
var url = 'mysite.com/index.php?page=post&see=11';

//with javascript
var jsBtn = document.getElementById('jsBtn'); //get the <a> with id 'jsBtn'
jsBtn.setAttribute('href', addNew(url)); //set the attribute 'href' with the new one

//with jQuery
var jqBtn = $('#jqBtn'); //get the <a> with id 'jqBtn'
jqBtn.attr('href', addNew(url)); //change the 'href' attribute with the new url

//function to add 'new' to the array of strings (created with the url string)
function addNew (link){
    var newUrl = link.split('/'); 
    newUrl.splice(1, 0, 'new'); 
    newUrl = newUrl.join('/');
    return newUrl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="jsBtn" href="#">javascript anchor</a>

<hr>

<a id="jqBtn" href="#">jQuery anchor</a>
```

Comment: <script>
var url = window.location.hostname + 'new/' + window.location.pathname;
</script>

Comment: but how can i do what this code work only one href  <a href="#" >my link</a>

Comment: Add one `id` to this `<a>`. Then you can use jQuery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), or javascript [.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Comment: plz show example

Comment: Check updated answer. :)

Comment: but i change all href  they have id="jsBtn" or not

Comment: The id is the identifier, they should be unique. If you target the ID, you will get only one `<a>` tag.

Comment: <a id="mylink" href="#">jjquery anchor</a>   for only this id href, with jquery code witch can i use. your examples didn't works

Comment: `$('#mylink')` with jQuery, or `document.getElementById('mylink')` with pure javascript.

Comment: <a id="mylink" href="#">jjquery anchor</a> for only this id href, with jquery code witch can i use. your examples didn't works

Comment: `$('#mylink').attr('href', 'mysite.com/new/index.php?page=post&see=11')` doesn't work?

Comment: i need simple code   witch get url were i am now , add  /new/  and gives my this link  in my link <a id="mylink" href="#">link</a>

Comment: `$('#mylink').attr('href', window.location.hostname + 'new/' + window.location.pathname);`...

Comment: this is correct : <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>  
$('#mylink').attr('href', window.location.hostname + 'new/' + window.location.pathname);
</script>

<a id="mylink" href="#">link</a>   ??

Comment: plz give full example

Comment: give my full example